# I am not able to write javascript array variables values into CSV file in a Given pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, jsp

I have three javascript variables by name Area, Device and Problem. I want to store values of these variables into a CSV file one by one as given in the image attached with this and download that sheet on click of download button.Both jsp and javascript are in same file.i have tried the below so far.

```
 Sample.jsp

<form>
      <input type="BUTTON" id="DownloadBtn" value="Download">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var Area=["Area1","Area2"];

 var Device=[["device1","device2"],["device3","device4"]];

 var Problem=[[["problem1","problem2"]],[["problem3","problem4"]],[["problem5","problem6"]],[["problem7","problem8"]]];


$("#DownloadBtn").click(function() {
        var resp=confirm("Do You Want To Download?");
            if(resp){

                 var last = '';
                  for (var i = 0; i < Area.length; i++) {
                    var first = Area[i];

                    for (var j = 0; j < first .length; j++) {
                        var second= device[j];

                        for(var k=0;k<second.length;k++){
                            var third=problem[k];

                        var value= third.replace(/"/g, '""');
                        if (value.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0)
                            value= '"' + value+ '"';
                        if (k > 0)
                            last += ',';
                        last += value;
                    }
                    }
                    last += '\n';
                }

                var anchor= document.createElement('a');
                anchor.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(last ));
                anchor.setAttribute('download', 'sample.csv');
                anchor.click();
             }
});
</script>
```

Please suggest me any kind of changes or modification needed to get desired pattern. how this can be achieved as required in the image. Comment below for any kind of clarification on this question. Any suggestion would be welcome.

[image]